# Why is only the getter invoked on the inputText value expression?

Tags: jsf, el

```
<h:form>
    First Name: <h:inputText value="#{studentFormBean.fname}" /> <br/><br/>
    Last Name: <h:inputText value="#{studentFormBean.lname}" /> <br/><br/>
    Country : 
    <h:selectOneMenu value="#{studentBean.country}">
        <f:selectItem itemValue="Brazil" itemLabel="Brazil" />
        <f:selectItem itemValue="US" itemLabel="US" />
        <f:selectItem itemValue="UK" itemLabel="UK" />
        <f:selectItem itemValue="Myanmar" itemLabel="Myanmar" />
    </h:selectOneMenu>
    <h:commandButton value="Submit" action="FormResponse"/>
</h:form>
```

At this code, `"#{studentFormBean.fname}"` should point to `setFname()` in `StudentFormBean.java` but it point to `getFname()`. Why is this happened and how can I solve it?

Answer (score 1):

`#{studentFormBean.fname}` will use both the getter and setter if used in an editable value holder like `h:inputText`. It will **get** the current value when the input is rendered. It will **set** the submitted when the for is submitted (and validation and conversion have passed).

See also:

- [Debugging JSF Life Cycle - what exactly happens in each phase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21914216/debugging-jsf-life-cycle-what-exactly-happens-in-each-phase)

Comment: I think the setter will be already invoked at validation-phase even though the model will not be updated if validation fails.